# NetBeans - Web application - Web pages subfolder

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I created an Enterprise application, with an EJB and a war module. I added some XHTML files in the Web Pages folders organized like this:

```
Web Pages
    WEB-INF
       web.xml
    protected
       testNavigation2.xhtml
    testNavigation.xhtml
```

I also configured the Faces Servlet with the url-pattern *.xhtml.

Having deployed my application I can access without problems the URL: `host/projectname/testNavigation.xhtml`. The `testNavigation.xhtml` file is shown.

But I can't access: `host/projectname/protected/testNavigation2.xhtml`. Using that URL results in:

> HTTP Status 404 - /protected/testNavigation2.xhtml Not Found in
>   ExternalContext as a Resource

The server console (I'm using Glassfish 4.1) reports:

> Warning:   Context path from ServletContext: /meteocal-project-war
>   differs from path from bundle: meteocal-project-war Warning:
>   JSF1064: unable to find or serve resource,
>   /protected/testNavigation2.xhtml.

How can I make xhtml files accessible from subfolders? I did actually a lot of research on this and judging from what I've read the behaviour I'm experimenting seems weird.

I don't think this is needed, but I'll post the content of web.xml in case I'm wrong:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>protected/testNavigation2.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thanks for your attention,
I'll greatly appreciate any help you can give

Comment: "I created an Enterprise application"? Beam me up, Scotty, there's no intelligent life down here.

Comment: You might have forgotten to deploy the application after you created the folder named `protected` having that XHTML file - `testNavigation2.xhtml` under the application root. Redeploy the application all over again from scratch.

Comment: To expand the preceding comment. NetBeans basically requires a hard deploy whenever you create folders in your application. If it were to happen even after you made a hard deploy, scan the file system on your operating system to see, if there is a folder named `protected` having the said XHTML file in the deployed WAR file. The symptom basically is only that the newly created folder `protected` itself along with the mentioned XHTML file is unavailable in the deployed WAR file.

Comment: That seems to be what happened since thanks to your comment I solved my problem. Thank you so much Tiny!

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer so it might help others. You can then accept the answer after 2 days or so to show that the question is resolved.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I thought about it but didn't actually do it because since I'm new I didn't know if that was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer has been posted by Tiny in a comment. I report that here to mark it as an answer.

You might have forgotten to deploy the application after you created the folder named protected having that XHTML file - testNavigation2.xhtml under the application root. Redeploy the application all over again from scratch.

NetBeans basically requires a hard deploy whenever you create folders in your application. If it were to happen even after you made a hard deploy, scan the file system on your operating system to see, if there is a folder named protected having the said XHTML file in the deployed WAR file. The symptom basically is only that the newly created folder protected itself along with the mentioned XHTML file is unavailable in the deployed WAR file.

by Tiny